# OpenSSL RSA_private_decrypt() fails with "oaep decoding error"

Tags: c++, qt, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to implement RSA encryption/decryption using OpenSSL. Unfortunately my code fails during decryption.

I'm using Qt. So here is my code:

```
QByteArray CryptRSA::rsaEncrypt(QByteArray input)
{
    QByteArray result(RSA_size(rsaKey), '\0');

    int encryptedBytes = RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42, (unsigned char *)input.data(), (unsigned char *) result.data(), rsaKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

    if (encryptedBytes== -1)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error encrypting RSA Key:";
        handleErrors();
        return QByteArray();
    }
    else
    {
        return result;
    }
}

QByteArray CryptRSA::rsaDecrypt(QByteArray input)
{
    QByteArray result(RSA_size(rsaKey), '\0');

    int decryptedBytes = RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42, (unsigned char *)input.data(), (unsigned char *)result.data(), rsaKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

    if (decryptedBytes == -1)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error decrypting RSA Key.";
        handleErrors();
        return QByteArray();
    }
    else
    {
        result.resize(decryptedBytes); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

It fails in:

```
RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42, (unsigned char *)input.data(),
    (unsigned char *)result.data(), rsaKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
```

I have tried several things, but i can't find my mistakes.

Comment: Don't you have more info about what fails and where?

Comment: Here is the error message: 
error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error 
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
It fails in: RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42, (unsigned char *)input.data(), (unsigned char *)result.data(), rsaKey, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);

Comment: @Adri - delete the above comment. Information like that should be added to the question by clicking *Edit*, and not stuffed in a comment where its unreadable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error:0407A079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error
error:04065072:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:padding check failed
```

If `RSA_public_encrypt` succeeds, then set the size of the `result` array to `encryptedBytes`. Do similar for `RSA_private_decrypt`.

Also, its not clear what you are trying to do with `RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42`. That looks very odd to me. I would expect it to be `input.size()`. But I'm guessing you know what you are doing with you array.

There could be other problems (like the public and private keys don't match), but we'd need to see more code and parameters to tell.

Also, you should use the `EVP_*` interfaces. See [EVP Asymmetric Encryption and Decryption of an Envelope](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: I have found my mistake. It didn't really have to do with the functions that I posted, but the way I thought the RSA-Container class works. Turns out, I only need to load the private key for decryption. I used to first load the private key and then the public key, thus the RSA object only stored the public key and the decryption failed. I'll mark your answer as accepted because I changed "RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42" into "input.size()" even though the openSSL-Documentation says otherwise. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't see anything about `RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42` in the OpenSSL docs at [`RSA_public_encrypt(3)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html). Its OK to test `input.size() < RSA_size(rsaKey) - 42`, but the usage above is not correct. I believe the 42 is room for padding, and `RSA_public_encrypt` will fail if `input.size() + PADDING_SIZE >= RSA_size(rsaKey)`.