# OpenSSL RSA Decryption fails randomly C/C++

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I am implementing RSA algorithm where I am reading the public and private keys from .crt and .pem certificates respectively. It encrypts the data correctly but the problem comes in decryption. Sometimes it decrypts fine and sometimes it gives the following error:

> Error decrypting message: error:04099079:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error.

The decryption fails when the following if condition is true

```
if ((decrypt_len = RSA_private_decrypt(strlen(c), (unsigned char*)c,
        (unsigned char*)decrypt, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1)
```

The code chunk is given below:

```
void DecryptRSA(const char *message)
{
    char *privateCertPath = "privateCertificate.pem";

    const char *msg = message; //message in base64 characters
    BIO *bo = BIO_new_file(privateCertPath, "rb");

    EVP_PKEY *pri;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    pri = PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(bo, NULL, NULL,  NULL);
    if (pri == NULL) {
        /* Error */
    }

    RSA* rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pri);

    unsigned char *decrypt = (unsigned char *) malloc(RSA_size(rsa));
    int decrypt_len;
    char *err = (char *) malloc(130);
    string msgascii = base64_decode(msg); //converting 
    const char *c = msgascii.c_str();   

    if ((decrypt_len = RSA_private_decrypt(strlen(c), (unsigned char*)c,
        (unsigned char*)decrypt, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1)
    {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %s\n", err);     
    }

    printf("%s", decrypt);

    RSA_free(rsa);
    BIO_free(bo);
    free((char*)msg);
    free((char*)c);
    free(decrypt);  
    free(err);  
}
```

Comment: This isn't really C++, is it? I mean, yeah, you use `std::string` once (and for the minimum time necessary) while base-64 decoding, but other than that it's pure C and you won't find much help for your `malloc`-related problems in a modern C++ community. Having a [MCVE] would really help, especially if you could provide the failing input.

Comment: Agree that there is a mixture of C and C++ but the error is coming out from the if condition which is C++ and it is producing the following error (not every time).
`Error decrypting message: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error.`

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506611/openssl-rsa-private-decrypt-fails-with-oaep-decoding-error If you're suspecting memory problem, does the problem disappear when you increased allocated size? (like - double it) Does it sometimes fail for the same input or is input randomized?

Comment: Everything about that `if` is C. From C-style casts over `strlen` and the RSA function call (which is probably [implemented in C](https://github.com/openssl/openssl), not that it matters) to C-style error handling and `fprintf`. Not an ounce of C++.

Comment: Yes I have seen and tried this link. The input is always same. The encrypted characters are different but the length is same. So might not be a memory issue.

Comment: What does the `base64_decode` function return? Could be it returning bytes in `const char*` or similar holder, and sometimes 0 cause the string to be truncated?

Comment: Are you sure that the decoded `msgascii` does not contain any null characters? That would result in `strlen(c)` being different from `msgascii.size()`, with only the latter being what you probably want. Or, to account for what @hauron said: Where does `base64_decode` come from? Again, a [MCVE] would help us help you.

Comment: @Max
I am a beginner with C/C++ so please bear with me. I thought my question was clear enough to have the answer.

Comment: As you see, it isn't. Time to update your question and answer those comments (as an edit in your question) ;)

Comment: The problem is what @MaxLanghof pointed out. Ciphertext is essentially a sequence of random bytes, not a string. If your ciphertext happens to contain a '\0' byte then your decryption will fail. Instead of using `std::string` you should use `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: Thanks @hauron, your answer helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using strlen(c) in the if condition caused the char array to terminate when the encrypted characters contained a null character, so instead I used msgascii.size() and it solved the problem.